Who is the distant man in the final frames?
In Extraction (2020), who is the man Ovi Jr. sees in the distance in the very final frames? Is he really there (I doubt, or rather don't think, so judging by the events of the sequel)? Really there or not, is he Tyler? In any case, is that a metaphor?

The film's official audio description isn't much help.  "Ovi surfaces, wiping his face. He glances to his right. A burly figure stands beyond the edge of the pool. The credits appear"

@Valorum – Yeah. The person is blond which, after first viewing, made me think – “Is that Tyler or someone else? Is whoever he is, really there? If it's Tyler, is that a metaphor for Ovi Jr.’s safety being ensured with the death of the antagonist? Or does the scene have some other significance?” I think I imagined three possibilities – (i) the metaphor I mentioned and (ii) Tyler having survived underwater (since he can hold breath for a good while as mentioned earlier in the film), having escaped and actually being in the very final scene. Can't remember the third rn.

@Valorum – EDIT: That's why I love that ending so much. Raises questions  (Btw, only 5 mins given to edit a comment?  Gotta take care from now on.)

The director has intentionally left the ending vague in order to provoke precisely this sort of discussion amongst fans.

“What would hopefully happen is people will be discussing that afterwards, and you get to say which one you feel is right for you.”
‘Extraction’ Ending Explained: Director Sam Hargrave on What Really Happened

Note that test audiences didn't like the earlier version of the script where Tyler is explicitly seen to die.

“We had a version of the movie, and we tested it a lot, and it was not surprising that a lot of people wanted the character to live, and some people wanted him to die. People were torn; it was almost down the middle. We want to appeal to as many people as possible without compromising the integrity of the story. And so, we think a pretty good compromise is to make an ambiguous ending. If people on one hand feel like the story is complete and is a story of redemption through sacrifice, then for them, it’ll be where the kid is imagining [Rake standing there], and then now you go, ‘Yes, I’m satisfied.’ If you feel like you love Tyler Rake, and you love Chris Hemsworth, and you want a sequel, and you’re like ‘There’s no way, you can’t kill him!’ then that’s Tyler Rake standing there looking at you. So we kind of purposefully did not pull focus to the character standing there.”


As to the question of whether Tyler is alive or dead, that's neatly answered by the fact that he is seen to be alive in one of several planned sequels.

After barely surviving a previous mission in Dhaka, Tyler Rake retires from mercenary work to a cabin in Austria to recuperate.


Ohk… Well, that's smart. It does raise questions, which is what I love about that ending. The sequel actually had eliminated my guess of Tyler actually being in the closing scene, which made me more curious about that ending. Thx so much! :)
